# Wagtail "schedule_published_pages" Management Command

Tags: django, wagtail, django-management-command

I was wondering why my scheduled posts were not working automatically in Wagtail, but I see in the documentation that a management command is needed to make this happen. I am unfamiliar with writing custom management commands, and I am wondering how to make the `python manage.py publish_scheduled_pages` command fire off automatically every hour?

Where would this code go in the document tree? Is there code that I just need to drop in and it runs from there? Or is something required on the server to run these commands on a schedule?

Any help would be appreciated. I couldn't find any existing code anywhere for this functionality in Wagtail and I'm wondering why the button is in the admin to schedule a post, but the functionality is not already built in?

Comment: You'd probably setup a crontab on your server to run every hour (or every 5 mis, or every minute if you really wanted). It should: enter your environment and execute `python3 manage.py publish_scheduled_pages`. And that's it. You can also use a service like supervisor to run these types of tasks instead of cron jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably familiar with management commands since `python manage.py runserver` and `makemigrations` and `migrate` are management commands.

You can see *all* available commands with `python manage.py -h`

`publish_scheduled_pages` should be called periodically. Form the [Wagtail docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/management_commands.html#publish-scheduled-pages):

> This command publishes, updates or unpublishes pages that have had these actions scheduled by an editor. We recommend running this command once an hour.

Periodically executing a command can be done in various ways. Via crontab is probably the most common. To edit the crontab:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Add ([for every fist minute of the hour](https://crontab.guru/#0_*_*_*_*)):

```
0 * * * * python /path/to/your/manage.py publish_scheduled_pages --settings=your.settings
```

Comment: Note: If you store session data in your db, Django also requires to purge that data periodically. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store

Comment: I see. So this command is already written and built in, I just have to run it on the server every hour. I was unclear as to whether or not I had to write a custom management command to make this happen. Thank you for your guidance. I'll give this a try!